# Drawing and Editing in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, editing, cad, map-drawing

Is it possible to carry out vector editing functions in QGIS? In this case I have an imported shapefile of contour lines. I wish to be able to create a copy of a line, in-situ, trim it, then create a number of offsets at a specific spacing. In short, basic CAD tasks.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 3):

You can install [QAD plugin](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qad/) which does exactly what you want. It has trimming, extending, and other interesting tool like simple CAD, as you can see below:

[image]

This is the only tutorial I found of [QAD Plugin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uAFQRb04HsQ), but unfortunately it is not in English. But I think you can still follow because the commands are in English.

Comment: Awesome, any tutorials you know about? 
Thanks, N

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: Yeah, spotted that one. However my Italian not so great. 
Thanks

Comment: If you are familiar with AutoCAD, it will be easy to understand the process. I had experience working with AutoCAD software before that's why I found it very useful.

Answer (score 0):

The Advanced Digitizing Panel has tools that will be of use for you.  I use it to start a predefined point, move at a specified distance and angle to my point of beginning then begin digitizing from there specifying line lengths and angles.  Here's a video tutorial for more information on the panel and the related trace tool:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QsjmLa16obs

These tools became part of the standard installation as of QGIS 2.8.